# Kotlin datatype mismatch error

Tags: kotlin

**Error message** is given below:

> " Type mismatch
>    kotlin.collections.ArrayList
>   found 
>   ()->kotlin.collections.ArrayList "

while trying to create an object.

```
public class PhotoController : Typed2EpoxyController<ArrayList<TowerOrUnitData>, Boolean>() {

  override fun buildModels(activityData: ArrayList<TowerOrUnitData>?, data2: Boolean?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

    activityData!!.forEach {

      val activityDataArrayList:ArrayList<ActivityData>

      for (i in 1..5) {
        activityDataArrayList.add(ActivityData("activityName" + i,"activityStatus" + i,"70","25","Open x|Close y|For Review z"))
      }

      TowerOrUnitData{"nil";"nil";activityDataArrayList}
    }
  }
}
```

**TowerOrUnitData:**

```
data class TowerOrUnitData(val towerOrUnitName:String, val activity:String, var activityData:ArrayList<ActivityData>)
```

Comment: Show us your code and full error message.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov Added more code to make things clear. Added the full error message as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
TowerOrUnitData{"nil";"nil";activityDataArrayList}
```

to

```
TowerOrUnitData("nil", "nil", activityDataArrayList)
```

You have incorrect *[object creating](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)* syntax.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Yeah, I see. But you still can't create an object that way.

Comment: I am not calling a method/function, I am trying to create a new object of a custom data structure.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov When I do that I get following error.
"Unexpected tokens (use ; to seperate expressions on the same line)"

Comment: And that custom data class has that constructor that Alexander is calling

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov The reference link you gave points to java doc.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat - You need to use `,` comma, **not semicolon `;`**

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Look at the brackets more closely: `( )` not `{ }`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh when I use , I get following :-
"Unexpected tokens (use ; to seperate expressions on the same line)"

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat - Use `(` `)` round brackets instead of braces `{ }`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks. :)